# Why is this PHP if statement still including the content inside?

Tags: php

I want `parts/lesson-links.php` not to be included when `get_the_lesson_contenttype()` equals to **"Hint"** or **"Main Lesson"**.

So I did this:

```
  <h2><?php echo get_the_lesson_contenttype(); ?></h2>

  <?php if (get_the_lesson_contenttype() != 'Hints' || get_the_lesson_contenttype() != 'Main Lesson') { ?>
    <?php 
      include( locate_template( 'parts/lesson-links.php' ) );
    ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

But as you can see in this page: http://clo2015.chineselearnonline.com/lessoncontent/lesson-004-hints-and-tips/

`parts/lesson-links.php` is still being added. What did I do wrong?

EDIT:

Strangely it works without the `||`, only adding `Hint`:

```
  <?php if (get_the_lesson_contenttype() != 'Hints') include( locate_template( 'parts/lesson-links.php' ) );?>
```

Comment: That will always be truth. `get_the_lesson_contenttype` can not be both values. Learn about the difference between `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: @PeeHaa so what should I write instead?

Comment: I think you want `if (get_the_lesson_contenttype() != 'Hints' && get_the_lesson_contenttype() != 'Main Lesson') { ?>`. This way it will only be included if it isn't "hints" and it isn't "main lesson".

Comment: @chris85 No, but I want to exclude it if its `Hints` OR `Main Lessons` and to include it if it's something else like `Notes` and other names.

Comment: Try it out, put an else in if you want to test what does and doesn't process.

Comment: @chris85 you're right. Maybe I forgot `||` works for two assertions and `&&` for two negations.

Comment: @alexchenco I explain this to great depth in my answer.  Boolean negation can be tricky to comprehend at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up your `ANDS` or `ORS` (pun intended (I'm not funny))

```
<h2>
    <?php echo get_the_lesson_contenttype(); ?>
</h2>

<?php 
    if (get_the_lesson_contenttype() != 'Hints' && get_the_lesson_contenttype() != 'Main Lesson') {
        include( locate_template( 'parts/lesson-links.php' ) );
    }
?>
```

**Lets take a look at some boolean operations!  Here we gooooo.....**

You said...

> I want parts/lesson-links.php not to be included when get_the_lesson_contenttype() equals to "Hint" or "Main Lesson".

Well thats like...

```
if (get_the_lesson_contenttype() == "Hint" || get_the_lesson_contenttype() == "Main Lesson")
    DONT INCLUDE
```

ACTIVATE NEGATION!!!!!!! (Basically flip EVERYTHING!)

```
if (get_the_lesson_contenttype() != "Hint" && get_the_lesson_contenttype() != "Main Lesson")
    DOOOO INCLUDE
```